# SQL Array with Null

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I'm trying to group BigQuery columns using an array like so:

```
with test as (
   select 1 as A, 2 as B
   union all
   select 3, null
)

select *,
       [A,B] as grouped_columns
from test
```

However, this won't work, since there is a `null` value in column B row 2.

In fact this won't work either:

```
select [1, null] as test_array
```

When [reading the documentation on BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#using_array_literals) though, it says Nulls should be allowed.

> In BigQuery, an array is an ordered list consisting of zero or more
> values of the same data type. You can construct arrays of simple data
> types, such as INT64, and complex data types, such as STRUCTs. The
> current exception to this is the ARRAY data type: arrays of arrays are
> not supported. Arrays can include NULL values.

There doesn't seem to be any attributes or safe prefix to be used with `ARRAY()` to handle nulls.

So what is the best approach for this?

Comment: I have no experience about BigQuery, but just for bypass `null` maybe use `if null` function to convert it into a non-null value represent null? like if column B never should be negative set it to -1? this is just a method if I need to have a data represent "null" but can't actually use "null" .

Comment: Right. So I have to group 20 columns this way? It should work but not efficient. When I look at documentation there are plenty of examples with [1, 2, NULL] arrays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per documentation - for [Array type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array_type)

> Currently, BigQuery has two following limitations with respect to NULLs and ARRAYs:
>
> - BigQuery raises an error if query result has ARRAYs which contain NULL elements, although such ARRAYs can be used inside the query.
> - BigQuery translates NULL ARRAY into empty ARRAY in the query result, although inside the query NULL and empty ARRAYs are two distinct values.

So, as of your example - you can use below "trick"

```
with test as (
   select 1 as A, 2 as B union all
   select 3, null
)
select *, 
  array(select cast(el as int64) el
    from unnest(split(translate(format('%t', t), '()', ''), ', ')) el
    where el != 'NULL'
  ) as grouped_columns
from test t
```

above gives below output

[image]

Note: above approach does not require explicit referencing to all involved columns!

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea you could pass an entire row in `FORMAT()` that's very cool. Also I often work with `REPLACE()` or `REGEX_REPLACE()` but discovering now `TRANSLATE()`, which is a little mad and very useful. This solves the quite a bit of the problem. However, if there's an index on each row, I could not avoid feeding it to `FORMAT()` right? I'd have to pop it out after the array is constructed?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution---and I'm not a fan of it---is to use a combo of IFNULL(), UNNEST() and ARRAY() like so:

```
select 
       *,
       array(
           select * 
           from unnest(
               [
                   ifnull(A, ''), 
                   ifnull(B, '')
                   ]
               ) as grouping 
           where grouping <> ''
           ) as grouped_columns
from test
```

Comment: Still I can't quite understand why there's no way to have a null in an array while the documentation says it can. Also the documentation has clear examples of array with NULL, such as `SELECT ["coffee", NULL, "milk" ] as list UNION ALL SELECT ["cake", "pie"]`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way, you can replace NULL value to some NON-NULL figures using function  `IFNULL(null, 0)` as given below:-

```
with test as (
   select 1 as A, 2 as B
   union all
   select 3, IFNULL(null, 0)
)

select *,
       [A,B] as grouped_columns
from test
```